# Back with a harder poker probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Okay, so last time I got help figuring out a simple binomial coefficient misunderstanding. Now I'm trying to figure out what happens if the following scenario occurs:

Player $1$ gets a $5$-hand of poker cards and tells everyone that he did not get an ace. *(for the sake of the context, let's assume he's not lying)*

How big is the chance of getting $2$ aces for the second player?

#### Tried solution

The chance percentage will be the quotient of:

**combinations of $5$-hands with $2$ aces $\div$ maximum number of combinations of $5$-hands**

The number of combinations of $5$-hands is $\binom{47}{5}$ considering player $1$ has been dealt $5$ cards.

Here's where I'm stuck. I would usually do the following to calculate combinations of, say $2$ aces:

$$P = \binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{a}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{1}^2 + \binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{a}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$$

Where $a$ is the number of ranks we want to choose from. The issue is that the $a$ in our case would be totally dependent on what cards player $1$ got, right?

If player $1$ got 4 cards of the same rank, our $a$ would be $11$, and it could take on different values as well.

Is there any easy solution to this problem, or what would be the general method? I might add that I have not learned about *Bayes' theorem*, and so I won't be using it just yet.

Edit 1: I think the equation should actually be, not a $100\%$ sure though.

$$P = \binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\left (\binom{a}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}\right )^3$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we're trying to count the number of hands with *exactly* two aces. Since there are 47 remaining cards in the deck, which includes all 4 aces. Then, we pick the two suits for the two aces, for which there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of doing. Then, we pick the remaining three cards from the 43 non-ace cards. Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{43}{3}$$
ways of the second player getting a hand with exactly two aces.

Also, if the problem was asking for a hand with *at least* two aces, then repeat the process for getting three aces and for getting all four aces.

Now, we divide by the total possible number of hands, $\binom{47}{5}$ to get the desired probability.

Comment: Hmm, just posted by own answer simultaneously; but seems I'm wrong in my own answer. Shows how much I know, hah. I'll delete mine if you're certain of yours; not that I doubt you. I'll study yours so I can understand it fully. Edit. Yeah, your answer is right. Thanks man, really needed the help :)

Comment: @XMLParsing, I think there is some sort of overcounting going on in your answer. The $47-2$ includes the two aces you didn't pick, so if an ace (or two) is among the $3$ you pick from the $45$, then there is overcounting, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what he means by "I did not get an ace".  What if he got 2, 3, or 4 aces would he be lying?  "An" ace implies only 1 ace.

If someone had 4 wives at the same time and you asked him "do you have a wife"?  Should he say yes or no?  Which is more accurate?  I would say the most accurate would be "no, I have 4 wives!" because if he said yes, he is stating he has one wife and implying he has no more than 1 wife.

Comment: I like how you think. Actually these are the sort of things that teachers' often forget; sometimes you understand by context, but other times one can interpret something in many different ways.

Comment: Part of word problems in interpreting what they are trying to state vs. what they actually state.  In this case yes it is ambiguous, however lying is not just telling a nontruth, it is also being deceptive, so one can argue if he has 2 or more aces, he should not say "I don't have an ace" because it is being deceptive (although it could be true).  There is such as thing as a true lie if it is both true and deceptive (on purpose).